# AEM Querybuilder - How to return only the folders under a path?

Tags: aem, query-builder

I'm trying to rerun only the folders from a given path using query builder on AEM

Query:

```
path=/content/dam/we-retail/en
type=sling:OrderedFolder
p.hits=selective
p.nodedepth=1
p.limit=-1
```

Or URL http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.hits=selective&p.limit=-1&p.nodedepth=1&path=%2fcontent%2fdam%2fwe-retail%2fen&type=sling%3aOrderedFolder

[image: Screenshot of querybuilder test url]

[image: Screenshot of folders under we-retail/en]

The query returns 35 records, while there are only 6 folders under `/content/dam/we-retail/en`. How can i return only these 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking at returning only the direct children under a path, use the property `path.flat=true`.

```
path=/content/dam/we-retail/en
path.flat=true
type=sling:OrderedFolder
p.hits=selective
p.nodedepth=1
p.limit=-1
```

However, it is better to loop through the child nodes and identify the folders rather than querying in cases like this where you need only the direct children.

More about the [Path Predicate Evaluator here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PathPredicateEvaluator.html).